# Что такое "участие" и как оно вычисляется?

Tags: поддержка, мета

В [списке участников](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users) на Мете есть раздел [`участие`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation). Что это такое и как это участие вычисляется?

Comment: На [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145151/339911)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перевод [ответа с MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149097/751470)

---

На это в значительной степени отвечает всплывающая подсказка, которую вы получаете, когда наводите курсор на ссылку сортировки "участие":

> Участники, наиболее активные на этом сайте (суммарное количество сообщений, голосов, комментариев и правок)

-- это всё, что есть. Возьмите сумму этих четырех значений и отсортируйте пользователей на основе этих сумм. Единственные незначительные детали, которых нет во всплывающей подсказке - это такие вещи, как "не учитывать удаленные материалы", и тот факт, что "голоса" включают в себя принятие ответа, а "редактирование" исключает редактирование ваших собственных сообщений